# Close/return ResponseWriter from child function in Go

Tags: go, web, handler

I am new to Go and building web apps. An example of my handler is something like this:

```
func getAllPostsHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var posts []Post

    dbSesstion := context.Get(r, "database").(*mgo.Session)
    err := dbSesstion.DB(dbsett.Name).C(dbsett.Collection).Find(nil).All(&posts)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print("error: ", nil)
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    err = json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(posts)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print("error: ", nil)
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
}
```

My handlers have a lot of repeating error checking like this:

```
if err != nil {
    log.Print("error: ", nil)
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
    return
}
```

I want to make a function, which checks for error, print logs, write the response writer if neccessary, and return, but not only to the handler, but to stop all other response writings and return the handler itself. Is it possible to do so? I am thinking about panicing, but something tells me that its not the right way.

Comment: The correct way to return from a function is a `return` statement. Don't use panics for flow control. Put your logic into a function that returns an error (as opposed to directly into the handler), then you only have to write the error handling once.

Comment: What do you mean "return the handler itself"? If you return from a handler, it stops processing that request. A handler has no real way to stop all other requests from processing (goroutines cannot be interrupted that way). You could have your program stop entirely using `os.Exit` I guess?

Comment: I think you're asking if you can have a common function to do that error checking which will cause the caller (i.e., the handler) to return. You can't do that, and panicking isn't intended for general exception-style processing. If what you want to do is avoid repeating the code under `if err != nil`, you can put that code in a deferred function and just return at those points. One downside of that is that it may make the code more confusing, since the deferred action is defined somewhere else. You can also define that same function and call it explicitly before returning.

Answer (score -1):

You can't escape outermost function from innermost but you can at least compact code a bit by inverting control flow

```
err := dbSesstion.DB(dbsett.Name).C(dbsett.Collection).Find(nil).All(&posts)
if err == nil {
    err = json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(posts)
    if err == nil {
        err = somethingelse()
        if err == nil {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
            return //successfully
        }
    }
}
log.Print("error: ", nil)
w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
```

Comment: cloud programming - is a bad advice in 2K19